# Simulatenously small fractional parts

Tags: ergodic-theory

Dirichlet's theorem on equidistribtuion tells us that if $\alpha$ is any number, then there are integer multiples of $\alpha$ of arbitrarily small fractional part (well, Dirichlet tells us it for irrationals, and a basic argument works for rationals).

Suppose I have a set $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ of real numbers. Given $\epsilon > 0,$ can I find some $N > 0$ so that $Na_1, Na_2, ..., Na_n$ all have fractional part in $[0, \epsilon]$?

Comment: well, yes and no. Kronecker's theorem in dimension two: if $a,b$   are irrational and $1, a, b$ are linearly independent over the rationals, then the $na,nb$  are dense in the unit square. page 28 in Diophantine Approximations  by Ivan Niven.

Comment: On page 44, he points out that the theorem generalizes to arbitrary number: if $1, a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_M$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q,$  then the $na_1, \ldots , n a_M$ are dense (and uniformly distributed) in the unit cube in $M$-space.

Comment: The need for the linear independence condition can be seen by looking at an example. Say $a_2=1-a_1$. Then the fractional parts of $Na_1$ and $Na_2$ add up to $1$, so if one of them is near zero, then the other is near one.